# Using cu in WSL

Tags: serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to connect a serial device in WSL.

The device is named `Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge` and connected via COM3 port.

In Windows it is able to access the device through serial monitor, but how can I access it from WSL?

I tried:

```
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS3

$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS3 115200
stty: /dev/ttyS3: Input/output error

$ cu -l /dev/ttyS3 -s 115200
Connected.
cu: Got hangup signal

Disconnected.
```

I'm using WSL2 in Windows build 19028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is in [FAQ for WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#can-i-access-the-gpu-in-wsl-2-are-there-plans-to-increase-hardware-support):

> As of right now WSL 2 does not include serial support, or USB device
> support. We are investigating the best way to add these features. However, USB support is now available through the USBIPD-WIN project. See [Connect USB devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) for steps to set up USB device support.

**UPDATE 09.11.2021**: There seems to be [a workaround](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/) which allows you to connect a USB device to WSL 2.

However, you can still use the WSL 1. See on the internet, how you can convert your WSL2 to WSL1. It is pretty simple: just write `wsl --set-version YOUR_DISTR 1`. For instance, `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1`. This command will convert WSL for the Ubuntu distribution to the version 1.
The next thing: Windows does not use the physical name of the device (as I understood it). That's why you have to create the physical name for the device in the **Windows Register**.

1. Find out what the device's physical name is. In order to do that open **Device Manager** on Windows, go to **Ports (COM & LTP)**, right mouse button on your CP210x device and left mouse button on **Properties**.
2. In this **properties**, select **Details** and then **Physical Device Object Name** for Property. In the value's text box you will see, how your CP210x named. [image: attachment_0]
3. Open **Registry Editor**, go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` and make a new string value there. The name is the physical device name from step 2. The port is the COM port from step 2. [image: attachment_1]